# Upgrade to Magento 2.2.2 problem with Zend/CLI

Tags: upgrade, magento2.2, cli, setup-upgrade, magento-upgrade

i'm upgrading to Magento 2.2.2.

After:

```
# composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.2 --no-update
```

and:

```
# composer update
```

I received:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. 

Problem 1
 - The requested package magento/product-community-edition could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes: 
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read
<https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

So I downloaded the RC from github and used his `composer.json`.

With this the update has started to download the new packages.

Then I cleaned:

```
# rm -rf var/cache/*
# rm -rf var/page_cache/*
# rm -rf var/generation/*
```

But trying to launch some command from CLI gives me the following error:

```
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Magento\Setup\Mvc\Bootstrap\InitParamListener#0 /home/pippo/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(156): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Magento\\Setup\\M...') 
#1 /home/pippo/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(281): Zend\Mvc\Application->bootstrap(Array) 
#2 /home/pippo/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Console/Cli.php(57): Zend\Mvc\Application::init(Array) 
#3 /home/pippo/public_html/bin/magento(22): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct('Magento CLI') 
#4 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 can only be downloaded from the Magento servers, they require autentication. You'll have to get your public and private keys from Magento first. More info [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html).

If you've already done this, can you add upload composer.json here? Maybe there's an issue there. For example the Magento repo can be missing under `repositories`. Example:

```
"Magento Marketplace": {
  "type": "composer",
  "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
}
```

Comment: Official releases and development are in github, the 2.2.2 version of composer.json is [here][1]

[1]: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/composer.json